# Jenkins email notification plugin show the error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to activate the jenkiens email notification so each time job fiish we recive email. After setting all the requried fields I see the following error. I also check Stack old question and I have deactivate the 2 factor auth of gmail and allow less secure application. Any help will be great.

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt
534-5.7.14 tQUWSlnAppJT7Wy70oFUKXPQ00YVYqjvjHvbaGSAtMnT8Zgm4OEuZwZqYv-bWYaL_ZkuX
534-5.7.14 IeIBEpCCEBvE-HLYDV-q9kMn7bCaZcSEExlRpvIOWygEzzq-xFIUj7td3tW-sLUm>
534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 b11-20020a92c56b000000b002c76a618f52sm12049894ilj.63 - gsmtp


    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)

    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)

    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)

    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:728)

    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:398)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:410)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:78)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
```

My Setting page images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell exactly where the problem is, but its clearly an authorization issue. You could try using another mail service provider to see if you get the same error and determine if it is a problem with your account or with the plugin.

Comment: I just authorized my Pc and it start working. Thanks.